# How to take label values dynamically in React js?

Tags: reactjs, forms, frontend, mern

I am trying to get a attribute input for the label tag while rendering the component. Using props to do this but its giving the following error-

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'props')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'props')

```
function SectionInput()  {

    const {label} = this.props;
    return (<div>
        <form>
            {label && <label>{label}</label>}
            <input type="text" props />
        </form>
    </div>
    );
}
```

the above is my component

```
<SectionInput label="Title"/>
```

This is how I'm using it

[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkee5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a functional component, accessing props from it is done by using the parameter of the function.

```js
function SectionInput(props)  {

    const {label} = props;
    return (<div>
        <form>
            {label && <label>{label}</label>}
            <input type="text" props />
        </form>
    </div>
    );
}
```

What you are doing is: Accessing the `props` from `this` that does not have it. Accessing it with `this.props` can be done with class components.

Comment: Thankyou!!
I am a complete react noob

Comment: No problem. There is a learning curve in programming. Try to zoom out sometimes to get the idea of what could be a problem. In your case you by using `this` and chaining some property, you can see that this is not defined. In that case you dig a bit on how this works in JS and what can you get out of there. From the hindsight it may look easy, but the debugging style is something that is important in every day work. Good luck